# How to using redirection to create a file

Tags: linux, terminal, vi

I have a linux script that generates a string and prints it to the console. I want this string to be the name of a file and open it for editing in vi. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
vi -- "$(your-script)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the backtick char to escape the script: (on the same key as the tilde ~ char)

> vi `./script`

And if the output has spaces that you stil want to see as a single parameter:

> vi "`./script`"

test it:

> vi "`echo This is my new filename.txt`"

Answer (score 0):

Does your script do this?

```
var=somestring
echo $var
```

That prints `simplestring` on the console

But this...

```
var=somestring
date >$var
```

will create a file named `somestring` and put the date and time into it. But maybe you want to be really clever...

```
echo -n What file should I use for the log?
read var
exec >$var 2>&1
date
```

The -n tells echo not to emit a newline. The exec command doesn't execute anything, just changes the stdout (#1) and stderr (#2). The 2>&1 says to make 2 (stderr) go to the same place as 1 (stdout).